# How to update the value in for loop?

Tags: python

I don't know how to update the value. I want next value is only greater 1 than previous value.

In this code `4` will change to `3`, great. Since `4` changed to `3` so I expect `5` will change to `4` ...

```
my_list = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i, curr_item in enumerate(my_list):
    prev_item = my_list[i - 1] if i >= 1 else 0

    if curr_item - prev_item > 1:
        print(curr_item)  # -> 4

        curr_item = prev_item + 1
```

I got this

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

expected

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: why is that expected? what are you trying to do? where does the 7 go?

Comment: Please describe your problem better

Comment: I want next value is only greater 1 than previous value `if curr_item - prev_item > 1`

Comment: @Yaekiou please add additional information to your question, not to the comments.

Comment: Note that you have an apparent typo in your loop body: `mylist` vs. `my_list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update `my_list[i]` (*not* `curr_item`):

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i, curr_item in enumerate(my_list):
    prev_item = my_list[i - 1] if i >= 1 else 0

    if curr_item - prev_item > 1:
        print(curr_item)  # -> 4

        my_list[i] = prev_item + 1

print(my_list) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Writing `curr_item = prev_item + 1` *assigns* `prev_item + 1` to the name `curr_item`; here, `curr_item` is not something like a pointer in C.

---

If you want a non-destructive way, the following makes a new list:

```py
output = []
prev = 0
for x in my_list:
    if x - prev > 1:
        prev = prev + 1
    else:
        prev = x
    output.append(prev)
print(output) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Alternatively, using list comprehension and walrus operator:

```py
prev = 0
output = [prev := (prev + 1 if x - prev > 1 else x) for x in my_list]
print(output) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to make a new list?

Comment: @Yaekiou What new list? You didn't mention that in your question.

Comment: Sorry I forgot. I mean how can I use `append` method to create a new list instead of modifying the original list.

Comment: okay, I got it. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Yaekiou Oh now that you accepted the answer, I cannot but provide you an answer. I've updated the answer, please have a lookt at it.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the `curr_item` (and `i`) with the `for` clause in each iteration. you are free to do whatever you want with those variables, but at the beginning of the next iteration they will be set again.

i'm just re-writing your code to make this a bit clearer:

```py
for x, y in enumerate(my_list):
    i = x
    curr_item  = y

    prev_item = my_list[i - 1] if i >= 1 else 0
    if curr_item - prev_item > 1:
        curr_item = prev_item + 1
```

so whatever you do to `curr_item` in your loop body will be lost in the next iteration.